# VueJs cant access assets folder for images

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to display an image on my slider which i have on assets folder but i cant do it.

My folder Structure is like this

[image: I am On home.vue]

My code looks like this

```
home.vue

<img src="../images/firstslide.png"/>
```

The file is compiled i think also the image:

```
"images/firstslide.png?b20d27e52e45509537b8713af8b92eed   423 KiB [emitted]"
```

But the image itself its now showing.

Comment: are you using vue-cli? or laravel? or nuxt? or ?

Comment: if you are using vue cli the asset  path <img src="./image.png">

Comment: Im using laravel yeah, no vue-cli or nuxt
tried also ./image.png that doesnt work too

Comment: if it's laravel keep asset at laravel public folder then give path like this <img src="/image.png" alt="">

Comment: Oh thanks, thats actually worked

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using require like this:

```
 <img :src="require('../images/firstslide.png')"/>
```

Taken from:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/img-src-require-url-not-working/39704